# Upper and lower hemicontinuity of correspondences defined on natural numbers

Tags: continuity, natural-numbers, set-valued-analysis

My question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104948/continuity-of-function-defined-on-natural-numbers) question. I'm trying to apply [Berge's maximum theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem). I use notation from the linked source for the rest of the question. In my case, the parameter set $\Theta$ which indexes each optimization problem is the set of natural numbers. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, my feasible set $C(n)$ is a compact convex subset of a Euclidean space. My question is regarding the last line: "If $C$ is both upper and lower hemicontinuous ... " Specifically, just like [we know](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3104948/continuity-of-function-defined-on-natural-numbers) that a function defined on the set of natural numbers is always continuous, can we say something similar for correspondences, that they are always uhc and/or lhc?

More broadly, what would be a sequential analog of the statement of the Berge's theorem, if any?

Comment: Yes, every correspondence on the natural numbers is both upper and lower hemicontinuous. This follows from the opens et definition of hemicontiuity at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemicontinuity and the fact that every set of natural numbers is open under the usual topology.