Concept of continuity of functions whose domain is natural numbers
Following this question: Continuity of function defined on natural numbers
Do mathematician consider "continuity of functions defined on the natural numbers" to be a standard definition?
Indeed, when you try to formulate a form of continuity, you reach the same conclusion as: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3104955/588260
Therefore, I think it is nonsensical to use such terminology for at least the usual definition of continuity because it leads to continuity always being true.
Are there counter-examples that make this notion useful?
Do mathematicians talk about "continuity of functions defined on the natural numbers" usually?
I tried to imagine like a function whose domain "converges" like {0, 0.9, 0.99, 0.999, ...}  so one would find a "neighborhood" in the topological sense but I did not manage to formulate my thought well-enough.

No, they don't. The only exception is the limit of a sequence, which you could treat somewhat like "continuity at $\infty$.” But TBH, I don't see how this question is different from the one you linked to.

There are some useful examples of totally disconnected spaces, for instance, the $p$-adic numbers. But the discrete topology is not that interesting

Well, we always have the subspace topology of $\mathbb N$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology, so we do have a notion of continuity there, but that topology is the discrete topology, which means any function $\mathbb N\to X$ is continuous. So yes, we can talk about this trivial kind of continuity, even if we mostly don't need it. In particular, in the category of topological spaces with continuous functions as maps, there is no good reason to exclude discrete topoogical spaces from that category.

It's not nonsensical because it indeed satisfies the definition of continuity, if $f: \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.
There is no ambiguity here, for example for your own sake of convenience, one can't assume that let $f$ be a function which is discontinuous on $\mathbb{N}$. I understand that once the graph is plotted, it might give a sense of "discontinuity" figuratively, but if you only consider $\mathbb{N}$ and forget about the connected intervals. You can develop a feel for it.
The definition of continuity is such that there has to be a strech/connectedness in the domain to conclude for discontinuity, but $\mathbb{N}$ has "discrete-ness", hence $f$ defined on $\mathbb{N}$ manages to satisfy the definition of continuity.
Yes, Maths gets even weirder. Have fun.

Why would one use such terminology for such category of functions? Do you have examples of it being used (for the usual definition of continuity)?

One would use such terminology as it satisfies the definition.

Can you provide one or two examples of such terminology being used in said context in papers?

Refer to "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" By Rudin, chapter 4. You can find this example in any standard Analysis text, either in exercises or as example. Or you might see it as a function defined on finite subset of R to R is continuous.

Ok, so I found that on your paper it says : If p is an isolated point of E, then our definition implies that every function f which has E as its domain of definition is continuous at p. I acknowledge that the author uses this for a definition of a continuous function, but my question was more regarding non-pedagogical papers that use this terminology.
